# How to load a constant complex object to a stack using LDCInsnNode in ASM

Tags: bytecode, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation

I want to use ASM library to create a bytecode method that is capable of returning a constant value at runtime. One of class in the ASM I can use is the LdcInsnNode. So my sample code is:

```
class Myclass{

final const Object value; 

    @Override
    public MethodNode get(String clsName, String mhName){   

            int access = Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC| Opcodes.ACC_STATIC;
            MethodNode methodNode = new MethodNode(ASM5, access, mhName, type.toString(), null, null);
            methodNode.instructions.add(new LdcInsnNode(value));
            Type returnType = Type.getReturnType(type.toMethodDescriptorString());
            if(!returnType.getInternalName().equals(Type.getDescriptor(value.getClass))){
                methodNode.instructions.add(new TypeInsnNode(Opcodes.CHECKCAST, returnType.getInternalName()));
            }
            methodNode.instructions.add(new InsnNode(Opcodes.ARETURN));
            return new methodNode;

        }
}
```

My question is how to load value when it is an instance of complex type (user-defined class). The document for `LdcInsnNode` only says:

> /**
>        * The constant to be loaded on the stack. This parameter must be a non null
>        * {@link Integer}, a {@link Float}, a {@link Long}, a {@link Double}, a
>        * {@link String} or a {@link org.objectweb.asm.Type}.

```
 public LdcInsnNode(final Object cst) {
        super(Opcodes.LDC);
        this.cst = cst;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

The `LDC*` instructions only support (as of Java 7) ints, floats, longs, doubles, `String`s, `Class`es, `MethodHandle`s, and `MethodType`s. It's a special instruction for bytecode level constants, not whatever random objects you might like to create.

You can push a null value with `aconst_null`, but apart from that you'll have to use normal code, i.e. create the object with `new`, then `invokespecial` the constructor with the desired arguments.

Comment: To be more precisely, there is the special, non-standard possibility to use `Unsafe` to create classes which can indeed have arbitrary objects in their constant pool as [described here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31454520/2711488) but the patching happens when defining the class, not when constructing its byte code. [And as said here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25742154/2711488) using a code generation library which is not aware of what the programmer is hacking can lead to severe problems, i.e. the ASM library’s own code verification may fail on such code.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the accepted answer:

Probably the easiest way to do this is to define your constant class value as a Singleton in a static field of another class. This can either be a class you write in Java or a synthetic class. Then, when you need the value, just use getstatic to put it on the stack.